# Hibernate does not create columns of @embeddable classes by hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As you can see in this topic, [JPA how to supply inheritance relationships for embeddable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491938/jpa-how-to-supply-inheritance-relationships-for-embeddable-objects), I have embeddable classes for each unit type.
 I have an entity A with following definition

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_x")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "class_x_id")
public class ClassX  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4924441463209260247L;

public ClassX  () {
    super();
}

@Column
private String name;


/** rated Apparent Power. */
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "aColumn_value")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "unit", column = @Column(name = "aColumn_unit")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "multiplier", column = @Column(name = "aColumn_multiplier"))
})
private Temperature aColumn;
/** Reference short circuit voltage. */
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "bColumn_value")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "unit", column = @Column(name = "bColumn_unit")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "multiplier", column = @Column(name = "bColumn_multiplier"))
})

private Percentage bColumn;
```

}

I configured hibernate to create tables from my entities with create-drop.**class_x** table is created , it has only have  **class_x_id** and **name** columns. Columns of embeddable object are not created. I could not find any problem/solution about this.

Comment: Check the log when JPA provider is starting up. Remember to set log level  properly detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about my embeddable class definitions. I was using inherited embeddable objects. This does not work in JPA. Now, I have defined base abstract unit as MappedSuperClass. super classes are embeddable. So as a result embeddable objects are inherited from @mappedsuperclass. Actually I read that Jpa also does not suport this. But it works now .